# How to use GroupBy in Dataset when the key is not string

Tags: dataset

If the key is string, this code is working

```
dataset = Dataset[{
    <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>,
    <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>,
    <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z"|>,
    <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x"|>,
    <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y"|>,
    <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z"|>}];
dataset[GroupBy["b"]]
```

[image]

But the key is not always string(such as the result of `Counts`), for example:

```
dataset2 = Dataset[{
    <|"a" -> 1, 9 -> "x"|>,
    <|"a" -> 2, 9 -> "y"|>,
    <|"a" -> 3, 9 -> "z"|>,
    <|"a" -> 4, 9 -> "x"|>,
    <|"a" -> 5, 9 -> "y"|>,
    <|"a" -> 6, 9 -> "z"|>}];
dataset2[GroupBy[9]]
```

As we see, when the key is a digtal `9`, the code cannot run normally..How to groupy it in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must use `Key[9]` in place of `9`:

```
dataset2[GroupBy[Key[9]]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Note that dataset visualizer does not do a very good job with the result (non-string association keys often confuse it).  It is easier to see that we have obtained the correct result by unwrapping the data:

```
dataset2[GroupBy[Key[9]]] // Normal

(* <| "x" -> {<|"a" -> 1, 9 -> "x"|>, <|"a" -> 4, 9 -> "x"|>}
    , "y" -> {<|"a" -> 2, 9 -> "y"|>, <|"a" -> 5, 9 -> "y"|>}
    , "z" -> {<|"a" -> 3, 9 -> "z"|>, <|"a" -> 6, 9 -> "z"|>}
    |>
*)
```

**Query Operator vs. Normal Function**

This is a case where a query operator has different semantics from its liked-named function counterpart.

The normal function `GroupBy` takes a function argument for grouping purposes.  Using the string `"b"` as a grouping function does not produce a particularly useful result:

```
dataset // Normal // GroupBy["b"]

(* <| "b"[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>] -> {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>}
    , "b"[<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>] -> {<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>}
    , "b"[<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z"|>] -> {<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z"|>}
    , "b"[<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x"|>] -> {<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x"|>}
    , "b"[<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y"|>] -> {<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y"|>}
    , "b"[<|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z"|>] -> {<|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z"|>}
    |>
*)
```

When using the `GroupBy` *function*, we must use `Key["b"]` instead of `"b"`:

```
dataset // Normal // GroupBy[Key["b"]]

(* <| "x" -> {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x"|>}
    , "y" -> {<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y"|>}
    , "z" -> {<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z"|>, <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z"|>}
    |>
*)
```

By contrast, the `GroupBy` *query operator* receives special treatment.  The *Details* section of the `Dataset` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) says this:

> **Syntactic Sugar**
>
> Functions such as `CountsBy`, `GroupBy`, and `TakeLargestBy` normally take another function as one of their arguments. When working with associations in a `Dataset`, it is common to use this "by" function to look up the value of a column in a table.
>
> To facilitate this, `Dataset` queries allow the syntax `"string"` to mean `Key["string"]` in such contexts. For example, the query operator `GroupBy["string"]` is automatically rewritten to `GroupBy[Key["string"]]` before being executed.
>
> Similarly, the expression `GroupBy[dataset,"string"]` is rewritten as `GroupBy[dataset,Key["string"]]`.

It is because of this query syntactic sugar that we can omit the `Key[...]` wrapper for strings -- and only strings.  So in a query we can write `GroupBy["b"]` but not `GroupBy[9]`.

The moral of this story is that we cannot safely assume that a query operator behaves in exactly the same fashion as a function with the same name.